# Binding Custom Attribute Value with field name with this attribute using Data Contracts C#

Tags: c#, attributes, datacontract

Could someone tell if this is possible to bind custom Attribute value with the proprty to which it is applied?

E.G.

```
class Attr : Attribute
{
    public string PropName;
    public Attribute(string name)
    {
        //DataContract of name and attribute that it will be applied to
        ...
        PropName = name;
    }

}

//somewhere in code
class A
{
    [Attr("EXACTNAME")]
    bool EXACTNAME;
}
```

So when user enters not matching string\fieldname - code wont compile

Thanks!